# Combine two lists based on a column

Tags: python

I am trying to combine two lists based on a field (similar to performing an inner join)

List A : Name, Position, Employee ID

Sample Entries

> 1) Bob, Admin, 32443
>   2) Jack, Security, 5464

List B: Position, Tasks

Sample entries

> 1) Admin, Check system files
>   2) Admin, Add Users
>   3) Admin, Delete Users
>   4) Security, Perform review
>   5) Security, Check settings

I need the final output to be like this:

> Bob, Admin, 32443, Check system files
>   Bob, Admin, 32443, Add Users
>   Bob, Admin, 32443, Delete Users
>   Jack, Security, 5464, Perform review
>   Jack, Security, 5464, Check settings

Please guide me how to include such code in simple loops. I am new to Python
Thank you much in advance

Comment: How exactly are those lists? Do you mean dictionaries?

Comment: Have you tried using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html)?

Comment: @ Peter, they are not dictionaries. They are taken from csv files. Did some manipulation after that. After combining these lists, I need to combine the result with another list and then eventually copy to a csv file.

Comment: @b4hand, no I have not tried pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the Cartesian product, then skip items which fail the join condition:

```
((name, position, emp_id, tasks)
for name, position, emp_id in ListA
for position2, tasks in ListB
if position == position2)
```

If we use `itertools`, we can shorten this slightly to avoid nested `for` loops:

```
((name, position, emp_id, tasks)
for (name, position, emp_id), (position2, tasks)
in itertools.product(ListA, ListB)
if position == position2)
```

Both of the above snippets are generator expressions.  If you want a real list, change the outermost pair of parentheses to square brackets.

Comment: Sorry for the novice question. Still in learning stage! How do I use the above code to get to a list. ListC = (name, position, emp_id, tasks
for (name, position, emp_id), (position2, tasks)
in itertools.product(ListA, ListB)
if position == position2) gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @GayathriGopalakrishnan: Syntax fixed.  You'll need to use square brackets or pass it to `list()` to make a list.